# Generating node type at run time according to Object property in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have one bean class like this

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Node {
   String id;
   String value;
   // Composites, Node is having Node is having Node and so on
   ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();

   // and getter and setters for all these field. 
}
```

I want to marshal this object using JAXB. By default it will create the element with name "node", or if we change the root annotation to something else(say @XmlRootElement(name="someotherName")), it create with that name.

But I have thousands of Node object, and I want the generated element name should be as per "value" property of Object;
e.g.

```
 Node node= new Node("myID", "myValue");
```

and after marshaling it, it should generate node like this

```
   <myvalue>
     <id>myID</id>
   </myvalue>
```

Is it possible? I searched many places, but haven't found anything like this.

Also I want the "id" property as attribute(@xmlAttribute) but conditionally, say if size of it's child nodes(ArrayList) is zero then I want this(id) property to be treated as attribute, otherwise not.

Thanks

-Dharmendra

Answer (score 0):

This generic method

```
<T> JAXBElement<T> wrap( String ns, String tag, T o ){
    QName qtag = new QName( ns, tag );
    Class<?> clazz = o.getClass();
    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    JAXBElement<T> jbe = new JAXBElement( qtag, clazz, o );
    return jbe;
}
```

can be applied to a Node object:

```
Node node = new Node();
node.setId( "id-1" );
node.setValue( "value-1" );
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( Node.class );
Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
m.marshal( wrap( "", "myvalue", node ), System.out );
```

to produce

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<myvalue>
  <id>id-1</id>
  <value>value-1</value>
</myvalue>
```

A variable handling of a certain field, either as an attribute or as a child element, is out of the question, and, permit me to say: a bad idea. It is in conflict with all good practice of having a well-established definition so that all parties concerned know what to write and what to expect.